# Cannot send parameters in asp.net mvc 4 using ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to send form data to action method using ajax but it is not working, if i try without ajax then it work perfectly. I've searched internet but couldn't found any appropriate solution, i'm sharing my code please guide me.

HTML:

```
<form action="/sp/operate?id=38" id="PartialFormSubmit" method="post">    
<table id="MainTablePartial">
   <thead>
       <tr>
         <th style="width: 8px;">
            <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" />
         </th>
         <th>
            Part No
         </th>
         <th>
           MFG
         </th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td>
          <input checked type="checkbox" name="CheckBox" class="checkboxes" />
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="text" name="PartNumber" id="PartNumber0" readonly value="2005137-2" style="width:180px;" />
       </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>
          <input checked type="checkbox" name="CheckBox" class="checkboxes" />
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="text" name="PartNumber" id="PartNumber0" readonly value="2005137-2" style="width:180px;" />
       </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>
          <input checked type="checkbox" name="CheckBox" class="checkboxes" />
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="text" name="PartNumber" id="PartNumber0" readonly value="2005137-2" style="width:180px;" />
       </td>
     </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<button type="submit" name="request" value="Quote" class="btn yellow">Send Quote</button>
<button type="submit" name="request" style="margin-left:220px;" value="NoStock" class="btn red box">No Stock</button>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#PartialFormSubmit").on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var dd = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: $(this).attr("action"),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        cache: false,
        data: JSON.stringify(dd),
        success: function (data) {            
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (jqr, errorStatus, errorThrow) {
            alert("Some Error Occurred! ");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

MVC Action:

```
[Route("operate")]
[HttpPost]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public JsonResult PerformOperation(int? id, List<TicketDetail> ticketDetail, string request)
{
   return Json("message",JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

i'm getting "request" as null if i send form via ajax, without ajax it is working. Please guide me

===================

**UPDATE:**

Tried Stephen Code

```
$('button[type="submit"]').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var dd = $(this).serializeArray();
    dd.push({ request: $(this).val() })
    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: $(this).attr("action"),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        cache: false,
        data: JSON.stringify(dd),
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (jqr, errorStatus, errorThrow) {
            alert("Some Error Occurred! ");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

It is just calling error function "Some Error Occured!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submit buttons are not serialized using `.serialize()`. From the [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

> Note: Only "successful controls" are serialized to the string. No
>   submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted
>   using a button.

In any case `ticketDetail` will also be null because of the way you have named your controls and you have invalid html with all those duplcate ID's

**Edit**

To post back the value of the relevant submit button, modify your script to handle the `.click()` event of the buttons

```
$('button[type="submit"]').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var dd = $(this).serializeArray(); // serialize the form values
  dd.push({ request: $(this).val() }) // add the value of the button that was clicked
  $.ajax({
    .....
  });
});
```

Comment: Attach event handler to click of submit buttons, use hidden input with name="request" and set its value before calling `serialize`.

Comment: Well you could use `var dd = $(this).serializeArray();dd.push({ request: someValue});` but how do you know which button value to send? You really need to handle the buttons `.click()` event not the form's `.submit()` event

Comment: @StephenMuecke how i can submit form differently each time if i follow each button click approach?

Comment: I'll edit answer shortly, but as I indicated, with the code you have used to create your view, its not going to work any way

Comment: @StephenMuecke how i can solve this issue? i was finding and trying different ways from last 5 hours :(

Comment: Which issue - sending the value of `request` (see edited answer) or the fact that `ticketDetail` will be null?

Comment: @StephenMuecke your edited code is not submitting form though

Comment: @StephenMuecke i have updated my question with the code help u sent but It is just calling error function "Some Error Occured!". I have mentioned all the code i have edited. Please check

Comment: Well your form action attribute is `/sp/operate?id=38` Do you have an action named `Operate` in `spController`? The action method in your question is `PerformOperation` not `operate`

Comment: @StephenMuecke thats is a route name operate, i have updated my question again with route please check

Comment: Check the browser console - what error are you getting?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60657/discussion-between-usama-and-stephen-muecke).